# CSS wrap sub items like list items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a fix HTML structure. I can't edit in this case.
I'm using flex. I have list items with text: "some text" and I wrap it with flex. The "Something else" child is not wrapping as I want. How can I wrap the red border items like the normal list items?

Here is an image where u can see my problem: (last row)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc3cF.png

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.border-group {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.sub-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item border">SOME TEXT</div>
  <div class="item border-group">
    <div class="sub-item border">SOMETHING ELSE</div>
    <div class="sub-item border">SOMETHING ELSE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item border">SOME TEXT</div>
  <div class="item border">SOME TEXT</div>
  <div class="item border">SOME TEXT</div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap the "something else" divs like the "some text" divs.

Comment: You mean the space between them? you wana remove that without changing html?

Comment: remove `.border-group` classes from class name.

Comment: Yes. I want to see items like this: https://i.imgur.com/tbj8puR.png
So I want to wrap the sub-items too when it's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. `.border-group { display: contents }`

> display: contents makes that the div doesn’t generate any box, so its background, border and padding are not rendered. However the inherited properties like color and font have effect on the child (span element) as expected. (https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/)

I don't need the border so it's enough for me.

Comment: Hope your browser requirements are like this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest fix for this would be to remove the "item border-group" div tag and then just add the "border-group" class to the div tags inside it. Something like this -

```
<div class="list">
 <div class="item border">SOME TEXT</div>
 <div class="sub-item border-group">SOMETHING ELSE</div>
 <div class="sub-item border-group">SOMETHING ELSE</div>
 <div class="item border">SOME TEXT</div>
 <div class="item border">SOME TEXT</div>
 <div class="item border">SOME TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I really can't change the HTML in this case.